# Advice for long-term persisting using influx and redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, influxdb

Our architecture consists long-term and short-term analytics. 
Today we aggregate all our data using dropwizard and put it into Influx. Influx is easy to query as it's time-series based database.

The thing is that "today's" data getting old and therefor keep it on MS(millisecond) sampling on influx is a waste.

Influx introduced downsmapling feature where you can transfer ms's records into weeks/months, etc.. the problem is that we need to expend our queries and query from "downsampled" tables and non-downsampled queries.

we thought about an idea where we can use short-term queries for influx and downsampled data to put on redshift as a long-term persistent data.

what do you think? perhaps it's a waste or?

as requested adding more details:
 how many rows of data: we expect around 1000 requests per second. each request would be a record
 how complex are the queries: pretty straight forward (e.g how many transactions in the last day/week/year, how many distinct users have logged in, etc..)

how many concurrent users: pretty small. 50,100

Comment: i have some questions (please update your question): how many rows of data? how complex are the queries? how many concurrent users?

Comment: @JonScott modified the question as requested .

Comment: You can also consider using Yandex ClickHouse database as a scalable long term storage or even completely replace InfluxDB with it. https://clickhouse.yandex/